# Vector on a sphere

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, rotations

I have for some time tried to understand the math behind explained in this [post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/9691/generate-transformation-matrices-for-rotating-around-a-object), but seem to not grasp.  I think the way i visualize it might be incorrect, which make harder for me to grasp what is actually going on.

I understand how the Z-direction occur, but how do based on that determine the y and x axis, and how is well defined for all cases on the sphere?